# How do I give a GCP service account storage.buckets.list access with read only access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to do `gsutil ls` however that results in:

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ gsutil ls
AccessDeniedException: 403 xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
```

Can I give this permission with **only** read / viewer access IAM roles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You certainly can.  At a minimum, you can always create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) with exactly the permissions you want.  You do this by clicking the Create Role button at the top of the [roles tab](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles).  Then, once it is created, apply that role to your service account on the [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam), like any other role.

Alternatively, you can use the [same roles tab](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) in the cloud console to search for that permission explicitly to see which roles contain it and see if any would work for you.

In this case, I don't see an obvious default one that is limited, however.  That said,you could look at Storage Legacy Bucket Reader (`roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`) as a starting point for a custom role in this case -- if you select this role on the roles tab, you can 'Create Role from Selection' to use it as a starting point).

Comment: Thanks, yes I just had to create a custom role with a specific permission.

Answer (score 5):

The command `gsutil ls` lists the buckets in your project.

To list buckets you need the permission `storage.buckets.list`.

To list the objects in a bucket you need the permission `storage.objects.list`.

Neither of those permissions allows you to read an object. To read an object you need the permission `storage.objects.get`.

To only read an object, you do not need the list permissions. However, since you are using the `gsutil` command, you do.

There are several predefined roles that you can attach to your service account to grant the necessary permissions for `gsutil`.

Recommended:

```
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

Or the following two roles:

```
roles/storage.legacyObjectReader
roles/storage.legacyBucketReader
```

If you ONLY want to assign a role to read an object but not list them:

```
roles/storage.legacyObjectReader
```

Comment: -1 after I tested `roles/storage.objectViewer` predictably results in `does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project`

Comment: @kubanczyk - Thank you, you are correct. In the first part of my answer I provided the role to access objects. In the second part I answered to list buckets. I oversimplified the problem to the point that part of my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Read only permissions for a GCP GCS bucket as of January 2022:

```
storage.buckets.get
storage.buckets.list
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.list
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Viewer" role for the project is probably what you are looking for to view all the buckets in a project.

Otherwise, by giving only the "storage object viewer" role, you can only view the content INSIDE the bucket, by going to the correct URL of the bucket.